# Jasper Reports Date doesn't change according to the given format

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to get the format of date I need, but the preview in iReport always shows the same format: dd/mm/yy, while after export to xls I get dd-MMM-yy in all cells.
my xml looks like

```
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                    <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="1a3dc360-984e-4029-af37-ffa54c84f1c3"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DECISION_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I use JRXlsExporter for export report to xls.
The field DATE type is

```
<field name="DECISION_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Can you show the elements you have inside your `textField` element?

Comment: @GustavoMeira Sure, <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
<textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">     <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="1a3dc360-984e-4029-af37-ffa54c84f1c3"/>     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATE}]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</jr:detailCell>

Comment: thanks. I'm not an expert, but I'll try to get more information from you, ok? You could even add this information to your question. What type is the field `DATE`? Is the report that contains the `textField` a subreport?

Comment: Just another thing. The content of your `textFieldExpressio` is missing a "]". Should be something like `<![CDATA[‌​$F{DATE}]]>`.

Comment: @GustavoMeira I appreciate you efforts ) I added new info to the question. Yes, I have additional ], it was a mistype when I answered you. No, it's not a subreport, it's a field in a table component which has it's own dataset.

Comment: Can you change the type of the field `DECISION_DATE` to `java.util.Date`? I made some tests here and I'm afraid the `pattern` property will only work for the "Date" type.

Comment: @GustavoMeira Then I am getting an exception while building the report: Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'DECISION_DATE' of class 'java.util.Date'

Comment: Oh yeah. Probably it's not able to convert between your datasource type and the `java.util.Date` type. Here I successfully created a field as a `java.util.Date` while its DB type was a `datetime` (on SQLite). Are you in the same situation?

Comment: @GustavoMeira No, my DB type is Oracle.Timestamp, and the DB is Oracle... I think there is another way.

Comment: Ok. I get you now. You could try something like `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mask for your time string").parse($F{DECISION_DATE}))` directly in your `textFieldExpression` ingoring the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: @GustavoMeira Excuse me, I see that in database the type is DATE, not TIMESTAMP. So I don't need to parse time. What is correct syntax for this case?

Comment: Weird. If your data type is `DATA` I thought Jasper Reports would turn it into a `java.util.Date` easily. But anyway, it doesn't matter your data type now, in the end your field type is `java.util.String`, so using the method I mentioned before should work.

Comment: @GustavoMeira Could you show me exact expression I should use? I don't completely understand the syntax, it shows January, 1 1970 for all dates now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the examples provided by the Jasper Reports library, I could find something like:

```
<field name="OrderDate" class="java.util.Date"/>

...

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="yyyy, MMM dd">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="54" y="2" width="87" height="10" uuid="1886b1ce-67ff-4457-89de-7baeae1446d0"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OrderDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Notice that (in this example report), the field `OrderDate` is declared as a `java.util.Date` object. So, I believe that for the attribute `pattern` to work, the `textFieldExpression` must contain a `java.util.Date` object.

But, in your case (as discussed in our comments), your field type is a `java.lang.String`. Something like:

```
<field name="DECISION_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

As the `textField`'s `pattern` attribute wouldn't work for your `DECISION_DATE` field, the solution could be formating your field value (a string) directly in the `textFieldExpression`, ingoring the `pattern` attribute. For example (based in your code):

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="1a3dc360-984e-4029-af37-ffa54c84f1c3"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("<your timestamp mask>").parse($F{DECISION_DATE}))]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Notice that where I put `<your timestamp format>` you should put the mask for your timestamp. When using SQLite with the `datetime` data type, the generated string is "2014-05-18 01:18:18" (for a `java.lang.String` field), so you could use the mask "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", for example.